# Interacting with WorldSpace UI with raycast in Unity

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, google-vr

I'm creating mobile vr game for google daydream and I want to add WorldSpace UI to my game and interact wit it. There is controller(works like Wii conroller) that tracks rotation, so I have rotating pivot in my game. [There](https://developers.google.com/vr/unity/controller-basics) is example of how this controller works. I thought that good way of doing this is using raycast to interact with UI(it would be shot form pivot), but after searching I haven't found anything helpful. Maybe there is another simpler way to do it?

Comment: Are you using google cardboard sdk for Unity?

Comment: @UmairM I'm using GoogleVR sdk, it's newer version of cardboard sdk

Comment: I meant the same thing. I worked with cardboard apps previously and can help if you need to interact by Gaze.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not using gaze anymore, I'm using controller which moves independently. Maybe I could use gaze input in this case as well?

Comment: You can use gaze for pointing and then controller to click on buttons etc.

Comment: Sure, but how can I make it interact with UI? From what I know gaze input is based on physics raycaster which can be attache only to camera.

Comment: Let me post the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Steps to setup Gaze Interaction in Google VR.

1. Add **Gaze Input Module** to `EventSystem` object:

   [image: EventSystem]
2. Add **Graphic Raycaster** component to Canvas(all canvases) and Assign **MainCamera** (child of **Head**) as Event Camera in the canvas component :

   [image: Canvas]
3. Add **GvrReticle** prefab as child of Main Camera. It should look like this:

   [image: Reticle]

Now your UI will respond to clicks (`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`) as usual. UI under Retical/Gaze will be clicked. All you have to do is map controller's input to click button in [Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html)

Hope this will help :)